# FreeBSD: Stable branch back to release

Tags: freebsd

I'm currently using FreeBSD 8-STABLE, and I'm just a little confused about what I will do when FreeBSD 9 is released.  Will I need to change anything in my stable-supfile?  How do I go about getting either 9-STABLE  or 9-RELEASE?  If I'm not mistaken, 8-STABLE will essentially become 9-RELEASE when it is indeed released, no?

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to continue to track -STABLE, you can just update your `stable-supfile` from

```
*default release=cvs tag=RELENG_8
```

to

```
*default release=cvs tag=RELENG_9
```

and then perform your csup/build/installworld as normal.  If you've customized your kernel, you'll need to review the new kernel configuration and merge your changes with it.

Technically, 8-RELEASE and 9-RELEASE each branched off of HEAD at different points in time, so it's not the case that 8-STABLE blends straight into 9-RELEASE.  Changes from HEAD or newer branches are often backported to older ones if they would benefit that older branch, but that is handled on a case-by-case basis.

Some further guidance, if you need it:

The build/install would be followed by running `mergemaster` to update and merge configuration files.  You'll also need to rebuild all installed ports to be compatible with the 9 [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (or else install the `misc/compat8x` port).

Be sure to read both `/usr/src/UPDATING` and the release notes for FreeBSD 9, to make sure that you understand the consequences of moving from 8 to 9, as there can be significant changes.

nixCraft has [a nice howto here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/freebsd-8-upgrade-tutorial/).  It's for moving from 7 to 8, and assumes you're using `portmaster`, but the procedure is generally the same.  It notes using `cd /usr/src && make delete-old` to delete old libraries afterwards; I'd forgotten about that.

Side note: If you don't need to tweak your kernel config much, I much prefer installing -RELEASE, and using [`freebsd-update`](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/updating-freebsdupdate.html) for binary patching.  It's much more maintainable over time.  In your case, since you're tracking -STABLE, this would mean a reinstall/upgrade from install media, because `freebsd-update` only supports upgrading between released/beta/RC versions of FreeBSD - but in my opinion, unless you need a custom kernel, it's worth it.

**EDIT**: Note that once you're tracking -RELEASE, you can use `freebsd-update` to upgrade from release to release, or from -RC and -BETA versions -- another reason why I prefer it.